# UISplitViewController popover button not displaying

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Is there a way to manually create a barButtonItem that can show the popover controller?

The only way I am attaching a button now is inside the willHideViewController delegate, and I think the button being passed there is automatically being created by the Split View.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a while back and thought I should come back incase someone stumbles upon this.

I was having an issue getting the buttons to appear because the delegate wasn't being called that shows them. It turns out the delegate wasn't being called because I didn't have the delegate set to the root view controller of the Split View controller.